# Train Neural Networks on a Data of type Table

Tags: matlab, neural-network, numeric

I loaded a huge CSV file of 2000 instances with numeric values and limited text values(some attributes have values like 'Yes' 'No' 'Maybe'. The above data was imported using readtable in Matlab.
I have want to train Neural Networks on the above data.

I used the Neural Networks gui and I was not able to see the new table as one of the options for loading data.

Hence, I plan to assign specific numeric values to text value of each attribute (Every 'Yes' will be 1 and every 'No' will be 0) and make it a matrix so that the GUI will recognize my data.

Or is there a better way to train neural networks on the above data.

Comment: You are probably approaching the problem correctly. Thats what I would do anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea is not only the correct approach, but the only approach. Neural networks work with numbers, so nominal values have to be mapped to numbers for it to work. However, there is one thing you should take care of: The range of each attribute of the input forms and interval. The range does not matter, if you normalize the attributes. So, if you have yes/no, you can map them to 0/1, 1/0 or -100/200. It doesn't matter, since they are the opposite ends of the interval they form.

However, usually nominal values forms a range. In that case, the ordering of the numerical values you create should retain the ordering of the nominal values. So in your case, if you have "no/maybe/yes", they should be mapped to [1,2,3] or [-1, 0, 1] or [100, 0, -100] or anything else that retains the ordering. However, if you use the mapping [no->0, yes->1, maybe->2], the network does not correctly map the nominal ordering to the numerical interval, so that attribute gives the wrong information to the network

Comment: Yepp, Ordering is important too.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: when you have more than 2 options in a nominal class and you do not know how do they distribute, a -1,0,1 is only viable if you assume a linear trend in the class. With this I mean, "maybe" is at the same distance of "yes" and of "no". If you cannot, then it is more viable to create 3 binary variables ("yes", "no" and "maybe").